# Firebase Storage and Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: firebase, cors, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm trying to download files from Firebase Storage through a XMLHttpRequest, but Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not set on the resource, so it's not possible. Is there any way to set this header on the storage server?

```
  (let [xhr (js/XMLHttpRequest.)]
    (.open xhr "GET" url)
    (aset xhr "responseType" "arraybuffer")
    (aset xhr "onload" #(js/console.log "bin" (.-response xhr)))
    (.send xhr)))
```

Chrome error message:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/[EDITED]
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3449' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Comment: Not enough rep for a comment, but the above way is still the right way. Just wanted to share the official firebase docs on this one: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#cors_configuration

Comment: youtube.com/watch?v=tvCIEsk4Uas&t=34s An explanation video

Answer (score 326, accepted):

From this [post on the firebase-talk group/list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/oSPWMS7MSNA/RnvU6aqtFwAJ):

> The easiest way to configure your data for CORS is with the `gsutil` command line tool.
> The installation instructions for `gsutil` are available at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install.
> Once you've installed `gsutil` and authenticated with it, you can use it to configure CORS.

> For example, if you just want to allow object downloads from your custom domain, put this data in a file named cors.json (replacing `"https://example.com"` with your domain):

```
[
  {
    "origin": ["https://example.com"],
    "method": ["GET"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

> Then, run this command (replacing `"exampleproject.appspot.com"` with the name of your bucket):

> ```
> gsutil cors set cors.json gs://exampleproject.appspot.com
> ```

> and you should be set.

> If you need a more complicated CORS configuration, check out the docs at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin#Configuring-CORS-on-a-Bucket.

The above is now also included in the Firebase documentation on [CORS Configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#cors_configuration)

Comment: Is there a way to allow all origins similar to Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *  ?

Comment: How can I find the exact name of my firebase bucket?

Comment: Where can I find the cors.json?

Comment: @user1311069 just use `"origin": ["*"],` instead of `"origin": ["https://example.com"],`

Comment: also, is there a way to remove this cors.json if I wanted to?

Comment: For some reason I am getting an error: AccessDeniedException: 403 Caller does not have storage.buckets.get access to bucket and I am logged with the right user using firebase login. Any help, please?

Comment: @isuru you should create a file localy named *cors.json* then run the command `gsutil cors set cors.json gs://exampleproject.appspot.com`.

Comment: Firebase really needs to figure out a user friendly way to do this.  Setting permissions on an actual Firebase database is not nearly this frustrating nor is setting S3 bucket permissions.  Strong preference for S3 at this point in time.

Comment: I agree with @MattJensen Firebase should allow configuration of cors through the console. Another paint point is configuring file versioning which also requires the use of `gsutil`.

Comment: I tried this solution but I'm not getting the file that's supposedly going to be downloaded.

Comment: If you don't want to install the util, a handy way is to go to https://console.cloud.google.com/home and click “Activate Google Cloud Shell” in the top right. This will open a shell with gsutil already installed, and with access to your firebase storage projects. (in the shell i used pico to create a json, then did the `gsutil cors set myjson.json gs://projectname.appspot.com` as mentioned above)

Comment: @Eindbaas Where did you put your json file?

Comment: How to configure it for localhost ?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors#gsutil

Comment: For localhost, include "http://locahost:port" in the list of origin e.g ["http://sitename.com", "http://localhost:4200"]

Comment: @Frenk Van Puffelen yet another of your answer saved me. Thank you for being around helping out since a very long time.

Comment: Where do i need to add the JSON file, to the bucket itself?

Comment: @Jim In your Firebase Console, go to Storage (on the left side panel), and on the first tab (Files) you will see the exact name of your bucket: `gs://YOUR_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com`

Comment: worked perfectly and nice to know about the Cloud Shell from @Eindbaas

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvCIEsk4Uas&t=34s

An explanation video.

Answer (score 284):

Google Cloud now has an inline editor to make this process even easier. No need to install anything on your local system.

1. Open the [GCP console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) and start a cloud terminal session by clicking the `>_` icon button in the top navbar. Or search for "cloud shell editor" in the search bar.
2. Click the pencil icon to open the editor, then create the `cors.json` file.
3. Run `gsutil cors set cors.json gs://your-bucket`

[image]

the content of cors.json

```
[
 {
  "origin": ["*"],
  "method": ["GET"],
  "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

Comment: Stuck at step 1. Please explain "and start a cloud terminal session"
I open the console and see no button, or link to "start a cloud terminal session"

Comment: It's the icon in the top right nav that looks like `>_`

Comment: Is there a straight forward way to pull the existing cors config first for reversion if necessary?

Comment: Did the trick! thank you. I must say, this could be so much simpler if it was controlled from firebase storage itself, under rules perhaps?! #google #firebase there's an opportunity here to enhance user experience.

Comment: I think they intend firebase anonymous sign-in to be how you can ensure that there is a firebase initialized with your project from your domain. @RodrigoRubio Match the request.auth.uid with resource.data.authorId, resource.data.members, etc. (or control calls in client code to non-anonymous uid's), and sign-in every user anonymously, at first. `getUserInfo = async (users) => {firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((meAuth) => {if (meAuth) {if (!meAuth.isAnonymous) {//good} else {//anon}} else {firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().then(() => {//no user}).catch((error) => {})})}`

Comment: @NickCarducci you might be right and i really like the anonymous facility, though it worries that it has a hard limit of 10 million from memory. This could be dangerous when you have a web app for a TV campaign for example where no one is expected to sign in or register.

Comment: @RodrigoRubio I am going to call getUserInfo whenever my threadVideos array is longer than 0 upon user-click of a button called _View Media_, that is where I populate my auth prop - where initially it is null.  this way `firebase.auth()` isn't ran every time the website is loaded! *facepalm

Comment: This is how you answer a question! Straight to the point. Worked perfectly.

Comment: Is there any wait time required? I set origin to "*" and it still complained Access to fetch at 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...' from origin 'https://....stackblitz.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Comment: @Weilies I am also facing the same issue, does it require any time waiting?

Comment: The trick worked, thanks for the simple & crisp solution.

Comment: you are the dude from youtube right.

Comment: the gsutil command worked for me, but in my case it was also necessary to use image.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'; on the client side

Answer (score 22):

Just want to add to the answer. Just go to your project in google console (console.cloud.google.com/home) and select your project. There open the terminal and just create the cors.json file (`touch cors.json`) and then follow the answer and edit this file (`vim cors.json`) as suggested by @frank-van-puffelen

This worked for me. Cheers!

Comment: The web console at console.cloud.google.com/home was giving me an error, but worked fine with the Google Cloud SDK Shell.

Comment: ... There open the terminal and ... How do you open the terminal? I see no "Open terminal" button on link

Comment: Make sure you're on the `cloud` subdomain, not the `firebase` one ("console.cloud.google.com/home") and look for the `>_` icon button in the top right.

Answer (score 11):

I am working on a project using firebase storage and the end-user needs a way to download the file they uploaded. I was getting a cors error when the user tried to download the file but after some research, I solved the issue.
Here is how I figured it out:

1. Download Google Cloud CLI
2. Log in using the CLI
3. Create cors.json file in the project directory and type the code below.

```
[
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "method": ["GET"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

4. Navigate to the directory containing cors.json with the Google Cloud CLI
5. In the CLI type: `gsutil cors set cors.json gs://<app_name>.appspot.com`

Comment: this is the correct answer for flutter web.

Answer (score 3):

another approach to do this is using Google JSON API.
step 1 : get access token to use with JSON API
  To get a token use go to : https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
  Then search for JSON API or Storage
  Select required options i.e read ,write , full_access (tick those which are required)
  Follow the process to get Access Token, which will be valid for an hour.
Step 2: Use token to hit google JSON API to update CORS

Sample Curl :

```
    curl -X PATCH \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/your_bucket_id?fields=cors' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer ya29.GltIB3rTqQ2tJgh0cMj1SEa1UgQNJnTMXUjMlMIRGG-mBCbiUO0wqdDuEpnPD6cbkcr1CuLItuhaNCTJYhv2ZKjK7yqyIHNgkCBup-T8Z1B1RiBrCgcgliHOGFDz' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: d19f29ed-2e80-4c34-85ee-c46c9058fac0' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
  "location": "us",
  "storageClass": "Standard",
  "cors": [
      {
          "maxAgeSeconds": "360000000",
          "method": [
             "GET",
             "HEAD",
             "DELETE"
          ],
          "origin": [
             "*"
          ],
          "responseHeader":[
            "Content-Type"
         ]
      }
  ]
}'
```