# download text file from firebase storage and displaying on a web page

Tags: angularjs, http, download, firebase-storage

i am building a web app using angularjs and am using firebase as my database and storage.

my issue is that i am trying to get a .txt file from my storage and display it in the browser, but whenever i make a request using the download url that i got using the firebase sdk i get a cors error.

i am authenticated in firebaseAuth and i have already been able to download images via the 'src' attribute.

this is my request:

```
$http({
        url: url,
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }).catch(function(e){
        console.log(e)
    });
```

I don't want to override the cors options if i don't have to. does anyone know how i can do this?

I am using firebase hosting to host the site, which shares the same url as my firebase storage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Storage and Access-Control-Allow-Origin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760695/firebase-storage-and-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: I have seen this post and it seems unlikely that I should have to alter my options. Especially since I'm using firebase's own hosting service which shares the same url as the storage

Comment: We don't automatically set up CORS, so you will actually have to set up CORS even if you're using our hosting option. In the future, we plan on adding our standard *.firebaseapp.com domain to the default CORS so you won't have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. 
Thanks Mike Macdonald for your comment.
I'll just do what it says in the other thread you sent me