# I am trying to zip a wav file from Firebase Storage but I am getting two errors

Tags: firebase, zip, firebase-storage, jszip

Pretty new user to Firebase here.  I am trying to zip a .wav file from Firebase right now and I am currently stuck on using jszip in order to zip the files from the download URLs I pull from Firebase. The URLs look like this:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/instasample-d8eea.appspot.com/o/kick%2F1.wav?alt=media&token=91612541-83e5-4e82-ae1b-b56bc421e36b
```

Every time I click the <kbd>download</kbd> button on my site, this function runs.  I successfully get the download URL, and put it into the `var urls`.

But I get an error that I am not allowed access to this file and an invalid state error. This puzzles me because I am able to manually go to the link and `right click` -> `save target as` just fine.

Thank you so much for any suggestions, go easy on me I am new to jszip and Firebase. This is my code:

```
    function download(downloadType) {
      //alert(downloadType)
        var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(downloadType + "/" + "1.wav"); //file name
        //todo: get 16 random file links, use for loop for thing below
        storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
          var downloadLink = url; //download link

          //////////////////////// do download stuff here ////////////////////////
          var zip = new JSZip();
          var count = 0;
          var zipFilename = "zipFilename.zip";
          var urls = [
            downloadLink
          ];

          urls.forEach(function(url){
            var filename = "filename";
            // loading a file and add it in a zip file
            JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
               if(err) {
                  throw err; // or handle the error
               }
               zip.file(filename, data, {binary:true});
               count++;
               if (count == urls.length) {
                 var zipFile = zip.generate({type: "blob"});
                 saveAs(zipFile, zipFilename);
               }
            });
          });
```

[image: Error message when I press download]

Comment: are you testing this from localhost?

Comment: @mjr yes I am. Would that affect anything?

Comment: Not sure if it's the full problem, but you're hitting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760695/firebase-storage-and-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: @MikeMcDonald thanks for the great suggestion, I just followed it and resolved the cross origin issue. that totally makes sense.  Now I am getting a Uncaught Error: This method has been removed in JSZip 3.0, please check the upgrade guide.  ;(   looks like i will need to change up the                  var zipFile = zip.generate({type: "blob"});  line of code

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @MikeMcDonald i fixed both of these errors with this post: [Firebase Storage and Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760695/firebase-storage-and-access-control-allow-origin)

I am now getting:

> Uncaught Error: This method has been removed in JSZip 3.0, please
>   check the upgrade guide.

Looks like I can finally move on. Thanks!