# Firebase storage download the raw text I uploaded and not just the url

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I uploaded a raw `String` 'Test' to the firebase storage using the sample provided [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_string) and it went through successfully.

But when I tried to "download" the string I uploaded, using the sample below, apparently he only example on how to download data from `firebase storage` it returns the url of the string file.

```
storageRef.child('path/to/string').getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  // I get the url of course
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle any errors
});
```

How do I get the contents of the file from the callback `url` which is 'Test' (The string I uploaded.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that in the Web Storage SDK you can only get a download URL that represents that data. You'll need to "download" the file using an `XMLHttpRequest` (or equivalent):

```
storageRef.child('path/to/string').getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  var XMLHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  XMLHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
      var response = xmlHttp.responseText; // should have your text
  }
  XMLHttp.open("GET", url, true); // true for asynchronous 
  XMLHttp.send(null);
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle any errors from Storage
});
```

Comment: It seems that this will now work because of CORS issues. :/

Comment: Luckily: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760695/firebase-storage-and-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: Sometimes I forgot that firebase is still based on google cloud services. Thanks Mike!

Comment: We try to paper over it so you don't have to think about it, but we're definitely glad it's there when folks need power user features :)

Comment: There should be a tab on the firebase console where you can use a virtual terminal `gutil`, more like for 'advance usage'. :)

Comment: Maybe I'm speaking too soon, but this just might be the life saver, I spent hours trying to get the raw text that I uploaded. Funny how there is an `uploadStriny(...)` method but no `retireveString()`, or even a convenient convertor. Firebase has been a lot of pain these days.

Comment: Ok as feared, I did speak too early

Comment: I uploaded a string, say 'Random'. Now it has no extension, but your method is not able to retrieve its current value

Comment: I get this error: `NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'https://my.buck.address'`

Comment: It does not withdraw the raw string I uploaded, unfortunately.