# Firebase: Access Files in Storage on Localhost

Tags: firebase, localhost, cross-domain, firebase-storage

I'm trying to test a program on a local server that references a file in Firebase storage.  Apparently I'm not allowed to do download files from my storage URL from servers other than Firebase's.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xyz123.... No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access. :8080/#/data:1 Uncaught (in promise)
>   UnexpectedResponseException

How can I allow my localhost to download files from Firebase storage?  I'm guessing that there's some way to allow this in the rules?
Here's what my rules look like now:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/xyz.appspot.com/o {  
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just realized this was already asked:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760695/firebase-storage-and-access-control-allow-origin?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Storage and Access-Control-Allow-Origin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760695/firebase-storage-and-access-control-allow-origin)

Answer (score 0):

Storage Security Rules must first specify the service (in our case firebase.storage), and the Cloud Storage bucket (via match /b/{bucket}/o) which rules are evaluated against. The default rules require Firebase Authentication, but here are some examples of other common rules with different access

```
// Anyone can read or write to the bucket, even non-users of your app.
// Because it is shared with Google App Engine, this will also make
// files uploaded via GAE public.
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```