# Firebase Storage/Bucket public upload with node.js

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Code:

```
var storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
var gcs = storage({
    projectId: config.google.projectId,
    keyFilename: config.google.keyFilenameFirebase
});

var bucket = gcs.bucket('project-id.appspot.com');
var destination = 'uploads/12345/full.jpg';

bucket.upload(myFile, { public: true, destination: destination }, function(err, file) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

My file is successfully uploaded to my firebase storage, but:

1. The file is now publicly accessible through the url:
   https://storage.googleapis.com/project-id.appspot.com/uploads/12345/full.jpg. Can I use this fixed URL in my App or is it likely, that it will change or expire?
2. `public: true` seems to break the Firebase Storage UI:

[image]
The preview of the image on the right side is not showing and I'm unable to download the image via the download button. Also, there is no download url (which I don't mind, cause I can access it via the link above) and when clicking "Create new download URL" Firebase yields

> Error generating download URL

When removing `public: true` the preview is shown correctly and I can also generate a download URL. But the public url  https://storage.googleapis.com/project-id.appspot.com/uploads/12345/full.jpg won't work anymore, which is necessary for me.

So my plan is to stick to `public: true`, but it still bugs me, that the preview/download button is not working and it looks like a bug in Firebase to me. Can anyone confirm that?

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. I am trying to upload the image buffer to firebase storage. I can't see the image preview, I can't see the public url even with and without public:true also I can't download the image/file from bucket. did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) It will not expire as long as it is always public. (I added a link related to this at the bottom)

2) Here's the quick fix. (You can do either of the following)

- Add yourself in the default ACL (below is the command using gsutil)

> gsutil defacl ch -u your_email@mail.com:OWNER gs://your_bucket;

- Add yourself as a Storage Admin in the Google IAM admin console

Then reupload your file....

**TL;DR**

Here's the reason why, according to the [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/gcp-integration#google_cloud_storage):

> You can use the Google Cloud Storage APIs to access files uploaded via
>   Firebase SDKs for Cloud Storage, especially to perform more complex
>   operations, such as copying or moving a file, or listing all the files
>   available at a reference.
>
> It's important to note that these requests use Google Cloud Storage
>   ACLs or Project Level IAM, rather than Firebase Authentication and
>   Storage Security Rules.

With regard to the `public:true`, I think that it will only enable and create the public link. Refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#objects)

Answer (score 3):

Your URLs shouldn't change or expire, and they should be valid until revoked which can happen through an object update or explicitly through revoking a url in the firebase web console. At least to the best of my knowledge.

First thing that comes to my mind is that : have you configured CORS on the bucket? This could be one reason. [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760695/firebase-storage-and-access-control-allow-origin)

Second thing that I can think of is storage rules. If you have something like `allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;` you might want to remove those to make files publicly accessible. You can use something like this to make all files in a path public:

```
 service firebase.storage {
  match /b/XXXXXX.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
    }
  }
```

If you've already done these two things, then unfortunately it might actually be a firebase bug too. Best of luck!