# Firebase RealTime Database CORS Issue

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Realtime Database on my web site, all works fine, but, when I want to do auth with custom json token I am getting a CORS issue like this: "Request from another blocked source: the same source policy prevents reading the remote resource in https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyCustomToken?key=$somekey".

Thanks

Comment: Probably a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760695/firebase-storage-and-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: @Orlandster The dupe you linked is for Cloud Storage, where this question talks about RTDB.

Comment: @Yorbenys: to increase your chances of getting help, edit your question to include the  [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do you have  a Content Security Policy in place? If so, you need to allows XHRs to https://www.googleapis.com

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is old but I was in the same issue, so I post the solution for some one else having the same troubles.

To avoid the CORS issue you need to go to Firebase console -> Authentication -> Sign-in method -> Then, scroll down to the 'Authorized domains' section and add your IP Address.

Comment: i do it buy still cors error is show for me

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still looking for a solution to this, appending `.json` to my URL did it for me. E.g `https://example.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/data.json`