# Firebase Real Time Database - CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, cors

I've just set up a Firebase real time database with default configuration. I'm using JavaScript to import the Firebase SDK via CDN since I can't use npm for now.

I know several similar questions have been asked and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46963855/firebase-realtime-database-cors-issue) in particular is close to the problem I'm facing presently but none of the solutions there seem to work. I've allowed domains, edited the database rules for public access and tried different browsers but the problem persists.

Here's my import code:

```
<script type="module">
    import {
        initializeApp
    } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.11/firebase-app.js";

    import {
        getDatabase
    } from "https://XXXXX-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app"; //path to my db location

    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        authDomain: "XXXXX.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://XXXXX-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app", //path to my db
        projectId: "XXXXX",
        storageBucket: "XXXXX.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "1111111111",
        appId: "1:1111111:web:XXXXXX"
    };

    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    const database = getDatabase(app);
</script>
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
import {
    getDatabase
} from "https://XXXXX-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app"; //path to my db location
```

You can't import the API from the location of your database. You need to import the SDK from the CDN that it's on, similar to what you do for `initializeApp` right above it:

```
import {
    initializeApp
} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.11/firebase-app.js";
```

So something like:

```
import {
    getDatabase
} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.11/firebase-database.js";
```