# Firebase "Access to Font" error

Tags: firebase, cors, firebase-hosting

This may be an oversight but I'm using firebase and set up the `firebase.json` file which is a mixture of auto-generation and copying the headers block from Firebase's documentation. The issue is, my fonts refuse to allow me access even though my file looks like this:

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source" : "**/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff)",
        "headers" : [{
          "key" : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
          "value" : "*"
        }]
      }, {
        "source" : "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg)",
        "headers" : [{
          "key" : "Cache-Control",
          "value" : "max-age=7200"
      }]
    }]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
}
```

This is the CORS error I'm getting:

`Access to Font {Firebase font url}. {Firebase font url} from origin {Firebase project url} has been blocked by CORS policy. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin {Firebase project url} is therefore not allowed access.`

Side note: I have an images folder in which I am able to load those just fine. Is there something about fonts that require more attention?

Comment: Please don't show images of code and errors.  It's far better to copy the text into the question so it's easy to read and search.

Comment: Replaced the image with error text

Answer (score 0):

Firebase rolled out a new feature/tool that forces users to update the CORS settings for Google Storage. I found the answer on this StackOverflow question.
[Firebase Storage and Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760695/firebase-storage-and-access-control-allow-origin/37765371#37765371)