# Firebase Authentication 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'null'

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've just started learning HTML/CSS/Javascript, and am trying to create a simple log-in page with Firebase. I am unable to log-in existing users, and whenever I attempt to sign in a user, I get the following error in the console:

```
Failed to load https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/getAccountInfo?key=...: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'null' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

My API key is displayed above instead of '...'. Firebase outputs the following error message:

Error: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.

Below is my code.js file that is linked to index.html:

```
var normal = true;

window.onload = function() {
  addListeners();
}


firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if(user){
    // User is signed in so display logout page
    document.getElementById("submit_button_logout").style.display = "flex";
    document.getElementById("submit_button_logout").onclick = function() {
      logout();
    }
  } else {
    // User not signed in
    // alert("Please log in or sign up.")
  }
});    

function addListeners(){
  if(normal){
    document.getElementById("sign_up_a").onclick = function() {
      switchState();
    }
    document.getElementById("sign_in_a").onclick = function() {

    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById("sign_in_a").onclick = function() {
      switchState();
    }
    document.getElementById("sign_up_a").onclick = function() {

    }
  }

  document.getElementById("submit_button").onclick = function() {
    alert("clicked")
    login();
  }
}

function switchState() {
    normal = !normal;
    if(!normal){
      document.getElementById("sign_in_a").className = "inactive";
      document.getElementById("sign_up_a").className = "";
      document.getElementById("form_header").innerHTML="<h2>Sign up for an Account</h2>";
      document.getElementById("submit_button").innerHTML="Sign Up";
      addListeners();
    } else {
      document.getElementById("sign_in_a").className = "";
      document.getElementById("sign_up_a").className = "inactive";
      document.getElementById("form_header").innerHTML="<h2>Sign in to your Account</h2>";
      document.getElementById("submit_button").innerHTML="Sign In";
      addListeners();
    }
}

function login() {
  var usr = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(usr, password).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...
    alert("Error: " + errorMessage);
  });
}

function sign_up() {
  var usr = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...
    alert("Error: " + errorMessage);
  })
}

function logout(){
  firebase.auth().signOut();
}
```

I have double checked if I have correctly set-up firebase, and this seems to be the case. My index.html file looks like this:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>You already know</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IBM+Plex+Sans+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js'></script> -->
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.1/firebase.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
      apiKey: "...",
      authDomain: "...",
      databaseURL: "...",
      projectId: "...",
      storageBucket: "...",
      messagingSenderId: "..."
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  </script>
  <script src="code.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Thanks in advance for your help in fixing this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Storage and Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760695/firebase-storage-and-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: How are you loading index.html? Using an HTTP server? or is it using `file:///` protocol? If the latter, then that is your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get Firebase authentication working with my website. As suggested in the comments and other answers, the problem was that I was loading my index.html file with file:// protocol. As I have python installed on my machine, I opened my command prompt and went into the directory of the files used in making my website. Here, I called `python -m http.server` and navigated to localhost:8000 in my browser. The website works fine here.

Answer (score -1):

try using some of the server like node, apache http.