# How to display text in flutter from a text file which is in Firebase?

Tags: http, flutter, python-requests, future

My question is pretty much the same as this: [Displaying text from a text-file on Firebase storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51117119/displaying-text-from-a-text-file-on-firebase-storage)

Only I want to do it in flutter and I have tried so many things. So basically I created a `futurebuilder`, `future` is the `getDownloadUrl`. Up to this point, it's okay.

So moving on.

First, I tried nesting another `FutureBuilder`, where `future` is an `http` request to the url. The `future` does not have any data. I had my shiny little red box all the time, from the else clause of `if(snapshot.hasData()){....}else{my redbox}`.

Then I tried a stateful widget where I have the text as `loading...` and in the `then()` clause of the `get` request I called `setState` with updating the text to the response body. It also doesn't have any data.

The link is for sure 100% correct, tried it in python, in browser and the best part.... Tried it in a separate dart file. It printed the correct data. Then I imported it in my `flutter` app, called the function, and nothing happens. I just don't get it. Sorry for the messy question but I'm starting to give up. I like challenges in programming, but only if it has a reason to go bad and i can find that reason.

Comment: Please clarify your question and include code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: have you stored your data in **cloud Firestore** ? and you want to get this data in your app right ?

Comment: please add the code

Comment: Please, See this this answer and tell me if you need any help https://stackoverflow.com/a/65443888/11735843