# How do I read and write a text file from firebase storage in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I need to make a storage for my saved images in firebase storage.
Is there a way I can read and write to online text file on firebase storage in flutter?
Is there any alternative to make my images storage?

Comment: Hello Sam. I see this you're first question on stackoverflow. Usually it's a good practice to show what you did so far, the code you've tried, and where exactly you got stuck. Also it's a good thing that you also tried to read documentation by yourself. The question you asked is so far too generic. Hope you're going to have a great time on Stackoverflow

Comment: @Tizianoreica tbh this is exactly what i was looking for, i dont think that this question is generic

Answer (score 6):

It's so simple. Let's explain the solution with the example.

import the library as following :

```
import package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' as firebase_storage;
```

Secondly, get the firebase reference by :

```
firebase_storage.Reference ref = firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
.ref() 
.child('playground')
.child('/put-string-example.txt');
```

Third, to get the data from the current file you are in :

```
Uint8List downloadedData  =  await ref.getData();
```

Fourth, now you will get a value in Uint8List format,
you have to decode this value by Utf8Codec class that is an instance of the
default implementation of the [Utf8Codec] and you will get the result in String object:

```
print(utf8.decode(downloadedData));
```

Now for writing it's a bit easier :
Firstly, we have the String object :

```
String putStringText = 'Hello World';
```

Secondly, we write to the current file with firebase ref object :

```
ref.putString(putStringText,
metadata: firebase_storage.SettableMetadata(
contentLanguage: 'en'));
```

the first argument is our string the second one is the metadata that allows you some extra options like the contentLanguage param.

I hope you find it useful.