# "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" interacting with firebase from localhost

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, cross-domain

I'm following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@oleg.agapov/basic-single-page-application-using-vue-js-and-firebase-part-2-143a3084266f) as a way to get familiar with Vue.js, vuex, and Firebase.

I have set up a Firebase account and created a simple 'Signup' page per the linked blog post. I get the following error when trying send a create user request to Firebase.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: 
>       The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at 
>       https://www.googleapis.com/blah/blah.
>       (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘https://localhost:8080’).

The signup form triggers the following method:

```
  userSignUp () {
    if (this.comparePasswords !== true) {
      return
    }
    this.$store.dispatch('userSignUp', {
      email: this.email,
      password: this.password
    })
  }
```

Which in turn calls:

```
userSignUp ({ commit }, payload) {
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)
```

I am using `npm run dev` to host the files locally.

Do I need to add something to the request header from within Vue?

Comment: Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760695/firebase-storage-and-access-control-allow-origin