# React axios.get - Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, axios

I uploaded some mp3 files to my **Storage** in Firebase.

I am using axios in order to get the relevant files that are stored in the Storage.

Inside "rules" tab I changed the permissions to:

```
      allow read, write, request;
```

However, I still get an error when I start up my website:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 
'gs://******.appspot.com/****/****' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only 
supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, 
https.
```

This is my code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        allRecords: [],
}

componentDidMount () {
  axios.get('gs://******.appspot.com/****/****')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({allRecords: response.data})
        console.log(response.data)
      })
      .catch(error => alert("An error has occurred, please try again and check your internet connection."))
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong? I am totally sure that the address to the get method is fine (I just copied it from Firebase).

---

**Edit:**

I run the command

```
gsutil cors set cors.json gs://****.appspot.com :
```

[image]

And yet I get the same error when I load my website.

Comment: since its a get request are you able to hit the api in normal browser ?  like copy the url and paste in the browser and try to hit it. check any response you are getting . Also do the api requires any headers or some params to identify this is a valid user

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Storage and Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760695/firebase-storage-and-access-control-allow-origin)

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the CORS policy on the Cloud Storage bucket to download files directly in the browser that way. <sup>[1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#cors_configuration)</sup>

You can use the [`gsutil`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install) command line tool for that. A typical policy file for your scenario can contain these directives:

```
[
  {
    "origin": ["http://localhost:3000"],
    "method": ["GET"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

You can update the origin list with other hosts that you like to access the bucket.

Comment: I installed gsutil but it still does not work for me, same error. I opened the .json file, saved it in my project. Did I do it wrong?

Comment: The protocol scheme is necessary as well.

Comment: Which protocol ?

Comment: Listed origin should be valid URIs. See the updated sample policy file contents.

Comment: "http://localhost:3000" is a valid address. Did I create the cors.json file in the right place? (cors.json is in my project together with package.json) Also, please take a look at my question, I edited it and added a what I got after gsutil cors set cors.json gs://kollab-music.appspot.com in the command line.

Comment: added a screenshot

Comment: You seem to be running gsutil in a folder that is different from the location of `cors.json`. You can pass the complete path to the `cors.json` file when you run the command. `gsutil cors set <complete-path-to-cors-json-file> <bucket-url>`

Comment: Dumb mistake. Now I run this command from the location where the "cors.json" is located. But still, it does not work.... The <bucket-url> is the url that I copy from Firebase? I am confused. If so, then what is <omplete-path-to-cors-json-file> ?

Answer (score 0):

*Using an extension is not an ideal solution.* 
This sounds like CORS is not configured on the server, I'm not entirely sure, but check out this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37765371/7723554), Should refer you to [this group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/oSPWMS7MSNA/RnvU6aqtFwAJ).

Answer (score -1):

Install CORS chrome extension and enable it, this adds Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Methods and Access-Control-Allow-Headers headers for CORS.