# How to add CORS to firebase - Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, cors, google-cloud-functions

Setting up a firestore functions.https.onRequest, calling this on my frontend errors  *No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

Tried a lot of other answers but could not get it to work. how do I set cors up properly for google cloud functions?

I tried most of the answers on stackoverflow the past 3 hours.

- Adding the cors header to the bucket via gsutil (from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37765371/7151828), ? Don't know if that is something else, though...
- Read [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)
- I tried to do it like this function sample: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/time-server/functions/index.js

This is my attempt using cors middleware

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cors = require('cors')({
  origin: true
});

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();


exports.exampleFunction = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

  return cors(req, res, () => {

    // Forbidding PUT requests.
    if (req.method === 'PUT') {
      return res.status(403).send('Forbidden!');
    }

    //respond to CORS preflight requests
    if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
      res.status(204).send('');
      return null
    }

   // code ...
   res.sendStatus(200);
}
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm confused -- you say you're trying to set up CORS on a Cloud Function but you're referencing a bucket and Cloud Storage URLs. Which is it? Using the [cors middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) has worked for me and should be able to work for you as well, just read how to configure it.

Comment: I am also confused. So I thought that the Cloud Function is referenced in the CloudStorageBucket (as there is a project with the same name as my firebase project). Will try again using cors middleware in the cloud function. Thanks!

Please see my updated question, I am now using the cors middleware like in the sample function, but still get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use URL Rewrites to allow the function to be served under your domain**

Okay, the proper solution to this is to rewrite the function to use the domain name and therefore we do not even need cors.

under the hosting section in `firebase.json` add the following to the beginning of the `"rewrites":` section.

```
  {
    "source": "/api/functionName/**",
    "function": "functionName"
  },
```

And I called the request via:

```
// send data to cloudfunction
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', "https://example.com/api/functionName/?param1="+ this.param1, true);
xhr.send();
```

This allows to get the param in the cloud function via `req.query.param1`

Answer (score -2):

You mentioned getting this error in the front end - have you disabled CORS in chrome to allow for the requests to go through?

link: https://alfilatov.com/posts/run-chrome-without-cors/

Comment: Sorry, but that is not what I am looking for. It needs to work in production for everyone.