# Storing rich text in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have book summaries that I would like to show to users. What's the best way to store rich text in firebase to show to the user? Should I be using firebase database? I have a database with all the books and I was just going to create a column for the book summary text.

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the data to a format that can work in the database. This is really going to depend on your rich text editor.

For example, if you use Draft.js, there are functions `convertToRaw` and `convertFromRaw`.

Other formats, such as Markdown, is already in a format that can be stored in a database. Markdown is just a big text string.

Another possible option is to save your data in [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). There are libraries for encoding and decoding Base64 depending on your source language.

Comment: I have another question. Is there a way to set cors settings for firebase storage? I'm having trouble accessing items there from my local development.

Comment: It looks like this was answered in the stack overflow question around Firebase Storage and Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760695/firebase-storage-and-access-control-allow-origin