# Insert firestore uploaded image in jsPDF

Tags: javascript, image, firebase, firebase-storage, jspdf

I have an uploaded image in Firestore and I am able to get download URL in my Angular application.

Download URL is like:

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/appname.appspot.com/o/clinica%2Flogo?alt=media&token=123456789-2bf7-4711-ba17-d12345678

When I click on it web browser shows the image, but how could I include it in jsPDF document? I tried to do:

```
const doc = new jsPDF('portrait', 'mm', 'a4');
doc.addImage(this.downloadURL, 'JPEG', 30, 20);
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR Error: Supplied Data is not a valid base64-String jsPDF.convertStringToImageData 
at Object.x.convertStringToImageData (jspdf.min.js:50)
at Object.x.addImage
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [jsPDF documentation](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/) the [`addImage` method](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-addImage.html#%7EaddImage) accepts its `imageData` in these formats:

> `imageData`:  `string` | `HTMLImageElement` | `HTMLCanvasElement` | `Uint8Array`
>
> imageData as base64 encoded DataUrl or Image-HTMLElement or Canvas-HTMLElement

So you can't simply pass in a URL that points to an image.

A simple way to get the image into a support format is by creating a `img` element in code:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = this.downloadURL;
doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 30, 20);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Now I am getting this error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/appname.appspot.com/o/clinica%2Flogo?alt=media&token=123456789-2bf7-4711-ba17-d12345678' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Did you already search for that error message in combination with the Firestore Storage tag? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-storage%5D++No+%27Access-Control-Allow-Origin%27+header+is+present+on+the+requested+resource.

Comment: Yeah, I was able to allow download images after doing https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files. Now I can generate a pdf file with Firebase images. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I get this working doing the following steps:

First, follow this solution [Set CORS in your firebase Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37765371/13555353)

I used the following cors.json

```
[
 {
   "origin": [
       "*"
   ],
   "method": [
       "GET"
   ],
   "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
 }
]
```

Then just use the following code to read your url and add it to your pdf:

```
async generatePDF(your_image_url: string) {
  let imageLoaded: HTMLImageElement = await this.getDataUri(your_image_url);
  let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
  pdf.addImage(imageLoaded, 0, 0, 250, 250);
  pdf.save('test.pdf');
}



async getDataUri(url): Promise<HTMLImageElement> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      var image = new Image();

      image.onload = () => {
        resolve(image);
      };

      image.src = url;
    })
 }
```

Hope this helps you, I was searching alot for this solution, so shared as much as you can.

Regards.