# Three.JS and Firebase Hosting CORS Issue

Tags: javascript, firebase, three.js, google-cloud-firestore, cors

I am trying to load a 3D model using the Three.js MT: / OBJ loader.

Example here: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_obj_mtl

The problem is that the Three.js package needs the files and the code to have the same base path.

So if my model is at `3d.com` and my files are at `3d.com/files`, everything works great.

The thing is, when I use firebase storage to host my 3d files (that users upload), I get an error because the base path is not the same. Firebase storage files start with `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/...` - So I'm getting the CORS issue.

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to get around this?

You have to ensure that the backend service is correctly configured and sets CORS headers in the HTTP response. For firebase, I suggest you study the following thread:

[Firebase Storage and Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760695/firebase-storage-and-access-control-allow-origin)

Note, this problem is unrelated to `three.js` and a pure hosting issue. You will run into this security error with each form of AJAX request.

Comment: Thanks. The solution was creating the cors.json file and then running the google cloud command.