# Flutter web : How to fix CORS Error fo Google Apis

Tags: flutter, firebase, cors

In web Flutter app hosted on Firebase Hosting, I try to make some Google Api calls.

Like this :
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=tre&types=address&key=XXXXXXXXXX&sessiontoken=YYYYYYYYYYYYY&language=fr-FR&components=country%3Afr

I already try to configure cors for Firebase Hosting, it works for images downloaded from Firebase Storage, but do not works for Google Api calls...
Like : [access-control-allow-origin is not allowed error , but if omitted then is expected from get request Flutter web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62892376/access-control-allow-origin-is-not-allowed-error-but-if-omitted-then-is-expect/62900737#62900737)
I spent hours to try configuration.

Here is Flutter code :

```
final Map<String, dynamic> parameters = <String, dynamic>{
  'place_id': placeId,
  'fields': 'address_component,geometry',
  'key': mapsApiKey,
  'sessiontoken': sessionToken
};

final Uri request = Uri(
    scheme: 'https',
    host: 'maps.googleapis.com',
    path: '/maps/api/place/details/json',
    queryParameters: parameters);

final response = await client.get(request);
```

**EDIT**
this is network tab result :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=rue&types=address&key=XXXXX&sessiontoken=YYYYY&language=fr-FR&components=country%3Afr' from origin 'https://zzzzz.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Answer (score 0):

CORS errors would not be coming from Firebase Hosting, but from the Google APIs themselves.  CORS is a ***browser side*** safety mechanism, where the browser sends a "preflight" (an OPTIONS call) to the `fetch()` or `Uri()` URL that your code is about to call to find out from which hosts a page calling that API should be.  If the API (in this case, `maps.googleapis.com`) does not handle the OPTIONS request or replies with a restricted list, then your browser throws a CORS exception if the page making that API call is not coming from one of those restricted hosts.

Doing a web search for "google api 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.'" I found [this SO post's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42182716/229326).

Comment: so there is no solution ?

Comment: Look in the NETWORK tab of your DevTools.  See what the result  is of the "preflight" (OPTIONS) request just prior to the browser attempts to make the API call.  If the OPTIONS request comes back with headers that don't allow your current page's URL, then you have to look to solve that problem.  Again, you'll have to configure the APIs you are calling to fix the CORS issue, not your web code.

Comment: I've edited my post, I've tried to add headers with no effects

Comment: Right...you are trying to access an API from a site (`https://zzzzzzz.com`) that is not specified in the ALLOW headers from the API.  In fact, the API does not provide any ALLOW headers.  I have updated my answer with a link to another SO post that is likely going to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to solve CORS error is to add the following code in you
**project_root/web/index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.flutterWebRenderer = "html";
</script>
```

Comment: this solution do not works

Comment: How would that solve a CORS issue?

Comment: I was getting the same issue, when I added that script in my index.html, it was working fine