# How to fetch json file from google firebase storage

Tags: javascript, firebase

**Background**
I need to upload large product inventory to indexeddb on client side so that I can perform some offline operations. They json file size could be as large as 50 MB. So I uploaded the json file to google firebase storage with the intention to fetch the storage file, read the json and add them to indexeddb.

**Question**

what is the best way to fetch and read the file from google storage ?

Here is my fetch code

```
var fileUrl ="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/konstant-ccbcc.appspot.com/o/storeid.json?alt=media&token=8d56ba73-331e-452e-b0d4-e552264feee3"

function loadJSON() {

fetch(fileUrl)
  .then(function(resp){
    return resp.json()
  })
  .then(function(data){
    console.log(data)
  })

}
```

this is error I am getting

> Fetch API cannot load URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.
> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
> at loadJSON

Comment: When I go to that site it returns ```{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found.  Could not access bucket test-ccbcc.appspot.com",
    "status": "ACCESS_BUCKET"
  }
}``` is this what you want? I'm doubting it

Comment: @JonahG I have added the actual file url

Answer (score 0):

The storage file is not accessible publicly.
Add `allUsers` with Viewer permissions to the file permissions or add authentication to the request. Configure CORS, see [Firebase Storage and Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760695/firebase-storage-and-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: i have added the actual url

Comment: @learner101 Configure cors for your file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760695/firebase-storage-and-access-control-allow-origin