# Flutter Web: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' problem when loading Web pager from PC

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, web, browser, cors

I am working with Flutter 2.2.2 in the development of a Web application hosted in Firebase. The difficulty lies in loading the site the images from FireStore. If I open the web from any mobile's chrome browser, there are no problems. However, when opening the web from the chrome browser of the PC I receive the error: ... has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Both are running the most recent version of chrome.
Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Try this answer. Add relevant configuration for using GCP console. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58613527/11231634