# Not able to use firestore storage downloaded url from getDownloadUrl as image src

Tags: html, database, firebase

I am saving the download url from getDownloadUrl method in database to later use as image src.
The image shows correct src in the view source but the image is not loaded.

```
<img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/social-snap-1bdbd.appspot.com/o/images%2F614d7b76e842ab0c54eb6748.jpg?alt=media&amp;token=8207cf33-e239-4ff7-9f08-4f7d6fac0a99" alt="user" class="w-full h-full object-cover"></img>
```

I Have also enabled public access to the storage bucket but It is still not working.

Comment: Did this ever get solved, if so, how did you fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use it on a webpage it is probably a CORS configuration problem. You have to add CORS policy to your header.

For this you can follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58613527/5292951

If you want to allow CORS from any website just use origin ["*"], otherwise specify your domain.

Comment: I tried this but it still doesn't work. I was already getting Status 200 code but the image doesn't load.

Comment: What error do you get in the inspection window?

Comment: no error , the image just don't show up.