# Angular 8 - CORS error using HTTP to download file from Firebase Storage

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to download the contents of a video file from Firebase Storage using Angular 8's HTTP Client.

Given the URL for the file in Firebase Storage, the following code is used to download its contents:

```
  public downloadVideo = (url: string): Observable<any> => {
    return this.http.get(url,
      {
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
      }
    );
  };
}
```

The following error is received:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at [url for resource] (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.

I tried the answer at [Firebase Storage and Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760695/firebase-storage-and-access-control-allow-origin)

But, it did not resolve the issue.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance