# Do any of you use syncfusion flutter pdf viewer for web application?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, syncfusion, pdf-viewer

I am able to display pdf successfully with the following class in the my flutter mobile app . However, a blank screen poping up on the chrome.

I added the relevant scripts for the web to index.html.

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.4.456/pdf.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.4.456/pdf.worker.min.js";
  </script>
```

I am reading the url from firestore.

Chrome version: Version 103.0.5060.134 (Official Build) (arm64)
syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer: ^20.2.43-beta

```
    class View extends StatelessWidget {
  PdfViewerController? _pdfViewerController;
  final url;
  View({Key? key, this.url}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('CV'),
      ),
      body: SfPdfViewer.network(
        url,
        controller: _pdfViewerController,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that Syncfusion is commercial software, not open source.  You will likely eventually reach the threshold where you must start paying them to use their software.  Beware.

Comment: Thank you, are there any other pdf viewers for the web that you can recommend?

Comment: i found the solution on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58613527