# Google Maps Javascript API Version 3.54 breaks Angular Google Maps 13.2.2

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, cors

On Nov 16, 2023, I started facing the issue with Google Maps in my Angular Application. Google Maps is throwing 403 Errors, and the maps are not loading (shows a blank page). Though my API Key is valid.

Below are the configurations of my Angular and System Application:

- Application Angular Version: ~13.1.0
- Angular CLI Version: 13.1.4
- Node Version: 16.14.0
- NPM Version: 8.3.1
- OS: win32 x64

Error Image:
[image: 403 Error Image]

**CODE:**

index.HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular Map Issue</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_Key"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Google-map-component:
HTML:

```
<!--start:Map-->
<google-map class="map" height="95vh" width="100%">
    <!--start:Map Markers-->
    <map-marker *ngFor="let site of sites"
                [position]="{ lat: site.lat, lng: site.lng }"
                [options]="{}"
                (mapClick)="displaySiteDetails(site)">
    </map-marker>
    <!--end:Map Markers-->
</google-map>
<!--end:Map-->
```

TS

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { GoogleMap } from '@angular/google-maps';
import { SitesService } from '../core/services/sites.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-google-map',
  templateUrl: './google-map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./google-map.component.scss']
})
export class GoogleMapComponent implements OnInit {

  sites = [
    {
      "siteDisplayName": "Site Name",
      "streetAddress": "Address",
      "city": "City",
      "state": "State",
      "zipcode": "10000",
      "siteId": 1,
      "oldSiteID": 1,
      "siteName": "Name",
      "lat": 34.255555,
      "lng": -100.255555,
      "siteMap": null
    },
    {
      "siteDisplayName": "Site Name",
      "streetAddress": "Address",
      "city": "City",
      "state": "State",
      "zipcode": "10000",
      "siteId": 1,
      "oldSiteID": 1,
      "siteName": "Name",
      "lat": 34.255555,
      "lng": -100.255555,
      "siteMap": null
    },
    {
      "siteDisplayName": "Site Name",
      "streetAddress": "Address",
      "city": "City",
      "state": "State",
      "zipcode": "10000",
      "siteId": 1,
      "oldSiteID": 1,
      "siteName": "Name",
      "lat": 34.255555,
      "lng": -100.255555,
      "siteMap": null
    },
    {
      "siteDisplayName": "Site Name",
      "streetAddress": "Address",
      "city": "City",
      "state": "State",
      "zipcode": "10000",
      "siteId": 1,
      "oldSiteID": 1,
      "siteName": "Name",
      "lat": 34.255555,
      "lng": -100.255555,
      "siteMap": null
    },
  ];

  @ViewChild(GoogleMap, { static: false }) map: GoogleMap;

  constructor(
    private title: Title,
    private siteService: SitesService
  ) {
    this.title.setTitle("Site View Page");
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("ngOnInit");
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.sites && this.sites.length>0) {
      this.setMapBounds();
    }
  }

  displaySiteDetails(site: any) {
    console.log("displaySiteDetails", site);
  }

  private setMapBounds() {
    let bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    this.sites.forEach((site: any) => {
      bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(site.lat, site.lng));
    });

    let ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
    let sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
    if (Math.abs(ne.lat() - sw.lat()) < 2) {
      bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(ne.lat() + 2, ne.lng()));
      bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(sw.lat() - 2, sw.lng()));

      ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
    }

    if (Math.abs(ne.lng() - sw.lng()) < 2) {
      bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(ne.lat(), ne.lng() + 2));
      bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(sw.lat(), sw.lng() - 2));

      sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
    }

    this.map.googleMap.fitBounds(bounds);
    this.map.googleMap.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());

    this.setMapRestrictions(ne, sw);
  }

  private setMapRestrictions(ne: google.maps.LatLng, sw: google.maps.LatLng) {
    let options: google.maps.MapOptions = this.siteService.mapOptions;
    options.restriction = {
      latLngBounds: {
        north: ne.lat() + 1,
        south: sw.lat() - 1,
        east: ne.lng() + 1,
        west: sw.lng() - 1,
      },
      strictBounds: false
    };

    this.map.googleMap.setOptions(options);
  }
}
```

Packages Used:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-material-components/datetime-picker": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular-material-components/moment-adapter": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/google-maps": "^13.2.2",
    "@angular/localize": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.1.0",
    "@azure/msal-angular": "^2.5.8",
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.37.1",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^6.1.8",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^6.1.8",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^6.1.8",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^6.1.8",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^2.7.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^11.0.0",
    "@types/intro.js": "^5.1.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.178",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.5.30",
    "@videogular/ngx-videogular": "^5.0.1",
    "apexcharts": "3.33.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "hls.js": "^1.3.3",
    "html2pdf.js": "^0.10.1",
    "intro.js": "^7.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.29",
    "jstree": "^3.3.12",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.34",
    "ng-apexcharts": "1.7.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^13.2.1",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^10.1.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^14.2.2",
    "object-path": "^0.11.8",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.5",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.2",
    "socicon": "^3.0.5",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "xlsx-js-style": "^1.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.1.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.1.0",
    "@types/core-js": "^2.5.5",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.14",
    "@types/jstree": "^3.3.41",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/rx": "^4.1.2",
    "@videogular/ngx-videogular": "^5.0.1",
    "first-input-delay": "^0.1.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.2"
  }
```

To resolve this I have added a version number like this `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.53&key=API_KEY"></script>` and this is working fine but It is not working if I add any version except 3.53 or remove the version.

I Also tried creating a new scratch angular application with same configuration and version, but in that it is working fine even when I don't add any version number.

Currently, my Angular version is 13.1.0, and any Google Maps version other than 3.53 is not working for my application.

Additionally, when I don't pass the version in the Maps API URL in Angular Application 16, the maps work fine. However, if I don't pass the version in Angular Application 13, the maps do not work as expected. Is there any reason behind this?

Comment: I found few Google Issue Tracker, please find the links here:

1. [303223396](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/303223396) Original
2. [296455182](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/296455182) Duplicate
3. [299327268](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/299327268) Duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging more into the Packages, I found out that because of [Application Insights](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/issues/1905), the Google Maps API was throwing a 403 error. Hence to overcome this issue we need to add a config of excluding the Google APIs domain, which fixed the issue.

```
private initializeApplicationInsights() {
   this.appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({
      config: {
        instrumentationKey: environment.appInsightsInstrumentationKey,
        enableAutoRouteTracking: true,
        enableCorsCorrelation: true,
        correlationHeaderExcludedDomains: ['*.googleapis.com'],
      }
    });

    this.appInsights.loadAppInsights();
    this.addCustomTelemetryProperties();
}
```

After doing this, there is no need to add the version number in the script tag (Working for me).