CORS error when accessing Firebase Storage
I have a function on my Profile.js
and the idea is change the avatar of a user in firestore data//same logic when uploading image in the Singup process.
But im getting this error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/login-d16b3.appspot.com/o?name=avatars%2FU2O2of0JJZtwZqsLVVuQ' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

The code :
const handleAvatarChange = async (event) => {

  if (currentUser && currentUser.id) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];

    if (file) {
      const storage = getStorage();
      const storageRef = ref(storage, `avatars/${currentUser.id}`);

      try {
        await uploadBytes(storageRef, file);
        const avatarURL = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);
        setAvatar(avatarURL);

        const db = getFirestore();
        const userDocRef = doc(db, 'users', currentUser.id);
        await updateDoc(userDocRef, { avatar: avatarURL });

        console.log("Avatar updated successfully:", avatarURL);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error uploading avatar:", error);
      }
    }
  }
};

I hope you help me to fix this cors issues.

The error comes from Cloud Storage, not from Firestore. Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760695/firebase-storage-and-access-control-allow-origin and apply that already?
